# From MySQL to PDO - Storing User Specified Date Fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a profile page I coded in what is now deprecated php code.  Switching to PDO and learning as I go. I keep running into this issue where my date field will not store in the database.  I found a solution solves the problem (adding **mysql_real_escape_string** to the date variable) however I was told this isn't PDO.

Is my code right?  Is this a safe and effective way to format the form submit option?

```
//----------
//--My Submit Statement
//----------

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$user_id = ( $_POST["user_id"] );
$length = ( $_POST["length"] );
$ground = ( $_POST["ground"] );
$date = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["date"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO admin (user_id,`length`,`ground`,`date`) VALUES     $user_id,$length,$ground,'".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."')";
$q = $pdo->prepare($query);
$q->execute(array('user_id'=>$user_id,':length'=>$length,':ground'=>$ground,':date'=>$date));
} 
?>
```

The date is user specified.

```
//----------
//--My Call Statement
//----------

<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
$q   = $pdo->query($query);
while ($row = $q->fetch()){
?>
//Edited out beginning of table
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['date']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['length']; ?><?php if ($selected == 'metric') { echo "cm"; } else { echo "in"; } ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['ground']; ?><?php if ($selected == 'metric') { echo "cm"; } else { echo "in"; } ?>
//Edited out bottom of table
```

Comment: You can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're not using the `mysql` extension. You should use prepared statements with parameters when using PDO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info <-- read this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO (and MySQLi) bring prepared statements and parameter binding which is *far* superior to query string concatenation (which is what you're using, sort of).

You seem to be attempting parameter binding via your call to `PDOStatement::execute` but you've already injected values into the query string and you have no parameter placeholders.

Here's an example using placeholders

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO admin (user_id,`length`,`ground`,`date`) VALUES (:user_id, :length, :ground, :date)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
    ':length'  => $_POST['length'],
    ':ground'  => $_POST['ground'],
    ':date'    => $_POST['date']
));
```

You can also bind parameters separately (rather than in `PDOStatement::execute`) using `PDOStatement::bindParam`, eg

```
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id']);
$stmt->bindParam(':length', $_POST['length']);
// etc

$stmt->execute();
```

There's plenty of information around regarding prepared, parametrized statements if you're interested (which you should be). These would be a good start

- [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)
- [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

#### Update

You'll want to do the same in your `SELECT` query, eg

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_id = :user_id');
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: Why did my code require the strip tags code to make the date work and your code does not?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. If you have any resources to learn more about PDO in a friendly way please share!